# Wordpress search issue

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode

Hi i have a website on which i have a search bar on home page when i search something on it, it will show a number result Chapter/Post related to that keyword but when i open any Chapter/Post there are number of "drop-downs" in the Chapter page & i can't see the word highlighted for which i have searched for. Can anybody help with that to highlight text or it's background

For Example i'm searching for word **"Morning"** on this page https://policies.americanprep.org/
I will make the **background or word color** **"red"** on this page https://policies.americanprep.org/chapter-f-classroom-organization/?highlight=Morning?s=Morning

Comment: better post some code

Answer (score 0):

You need to change default wp_content/wp_excerpt in result page with something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['highlight'])){
    $content = get_the_content();
    $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', $_GET['highlight']));
    $content = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<strong class="search-highlight">\0</strong>', $content);

    echo '<p>' . $content . '</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>' . get_the_content() . '</p>';
}
```

Also you need to add css code for `span.search-highlight`

$_GET parameter `'s'` would be better to remove from url.